# Incrementing a number and adding a leading zero in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, leading-zero

The problem is with the numbers 08 and 09.  I've Googled this and found out the reason that 08 and 09 are problematic, but no solution.

This is a nonsensical example used to briefly describe my problem without getting into the details.

```
cursorDay=2;
let cursorDay=$cursorDay+1;

case "$cursorDay" in

1) cursorDay=01;;
2) cursorDay=02;;
3) cursorDay=03;;
4) cursorDay=04;;
5) cursorDay=05;;
6) cursorDay=06;;
7) cursorDay=07;;
8) cursorDay=08;;
9) cursorDay=09;

esac

echo "$cursorDay";
```

The output I expect is "03", and indeed I do get that output.  But if I do the same thing to try and get 08 or 09, I this error:

```
line 100: let: cursorDay=08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

The question is, is there any way to "force" it to treat 08 and 09 as just regular numbers?  I found several posts detailing how to eliminate the zero, but I *want* a zero.

Comment: You might get more insight in your problem when you realize you want the _strings_ "01" .. "09", not the _numbers_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you evaluate arithmetic expressions (like let does), a leading 0 indicates an octal number. You can force bash to use a given base by prefixing *base*`#` to the number. 
In addition, you can use printf to pad numbers with leading zeroes.

So your example could be rewritten as

```
cursorDay=2

let cursorDay=10#$cursorDay+1
printf -v cursorDay '%02d\n' "$cursorDay"

echo "$cursorDay"
```

or even shorter as

```
cursorDay=2

printf -v cursorDay '%02d\n' $((10#$cursorDay + 1))

echo "$cursorDay"
```

Please note that you cannot omit the `$` between the `#` and the variable name.

Comment: There's no need to specify base-10 for cursorDay, since it's the default. More to the point is that you let `printf` format the string representation of the integer using the `%02d` specification, rather than trying to add the "0" yourself.

Comment: No, the default is auto-detection based on the prefix. If you replaced cursorDay=2 by cursorDay=08 it wouldn't work without 10#. My understanding of the question was, that CptSupermrkt would like to use 08 and 09 as cursorDay values, too.

Comment: Ah, good point. I assumed the leading zero was for display purposes only. My comment about the default referred to interpreting a string value without a leading 0. You are, of course, correct that the 10# prefix is necessary to interpret "09" as the decimal number 9.

Answer (score 4):

A short solution without 'case':

```
((cursorDay++))                   # increment
cursorDay=0$cursorDay             # add leading 0
echo  "${cursorDay: -2}"          # echo last 2 characters
```

Answer (score 1):

Just prefix the number with '0'.

```
cursorDay=2;
let cursorDay=$cursorDay+1;

case "$cursorDay" in   
1) cursorDay=1;;
2) cursorDay=2;;
3) cursorDay=3;;
4) cursorDay=4;;
5) cursorDay=5;;
6) cursorDay=6;;
7) cursorDay=7;;
8) cursorDay=8;;
9) cursorDay=9;;  
esac  
echo "0$cursorDay";
```

OR

```
     case
     ...
    7) cursorDay="07";;
    8) cursorDay="08";;
    9) cursorDay="09";;  

let numericValue=$(expr $cursorDay + 0)
```